# как превратить ZonedDateTime в формат new Date()?

Tags: javascript

с бэка приходит такой формат даты '2020-08-11T14:07:08.259785+03:00[Europe/Moscow]'.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как его форматнуть в формат new Date()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так попробуйте

```js
let date = new Date( '2020-08-11T14:07:08.259785+03:00[Europe/Moscow]'.split('[')[0])
console.log(date);
```

Comment: Спасибо, я думала может есть вариант как то именно с самой датой поработать, хотя перепробовала почти все